# SQL Server buffer latch contention on INSERT into heap

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I have many concurrent sessions `INSERT`ing into the same heap table. No indexes, but there is an `identity` column.

This statement is showing high buffer latch waits.  The vast majority of the time executing this query is spent in those waits, which seems like contention or single-threading somewhere in the process.

If this table were a b-tree with a clustered index, I wouldn't be surprised -- that's a standard "last page contention" problem, especially with small rows and thus dense pages.  Except this is a heap.

What else should I look?

Comment: Why would you expect less latch contention with a heap? Latches serialize access to the same page by concurrent threads.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes, the only thing I find surprising is the _extent_.